# Catching InputMismatchException doesn't return the message

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

So I'm making this school assignment and basically need to make sure that the user inputs a valid option (1, 2 or 3).

I should of used switches but this is what I made:

```
private void choice() {
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = s.nextInt();
        if (option == 1) {
            start();
        }
        if (option == 2) {
            info();
        }
        if (option == 3) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        throw new InputMismatchException("Enter valid input");
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If you enter a number in the console it will return my message, if you enter anything else it will return "null". Why is that? Because if I remove the exception and look at the stacktrace (when entering a letter for example) it shows an InputMismatchException.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: For sure another exception is thrown, not an inputMismatch..

Comment: Look at the stacktrace. Is it from the InputMismatchException?

Comment: Catch Throwable below catch (InputMismatchException e) (Don't do it in production code) and just print the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void choice() throws InputMismatchException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = 0;

    try {
        option = s.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        throw new InputMismatchException("Enter valid input");
    }

    if (option == 1) {
        System.out.println("e");
    } else if (option == 2) {
        System.out.println("f");
    } else if (option == 3) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        throw new InputMismatchException("Enter valid input");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Test().choice();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Put int option, inside the try. Done.

Comment: It works for numbers, but if I type in a letter then I just get "null". I thought I caught the exception?

Comment: The problems is that your code is option never reaches the else statement. See the edit.

Comment: I edited the question, I remade my option picking and now it should reach it right?

Comment: The scanner.nextInt() method reads an int. if no int is found it will throw an exception and will never reach your if statement so you need to handle the exception during the input and pass it over to the method that makes the call. In this case main made the call so main handles the exception and prints the message.